# Capture external process output

Tags: c#, java, c++, process, stdout

Don't close it as duplicate, since I have a subtle but significant change from the similiar questions:

Is it possible to capture output of an external process (i.e. stdout) in java, **when I didn't create the process**, and all I know is the process name?

I'm running on windows 7.

**EDIT:**

If there is a way to do it in other language (C#\C++), then I can write a "CaptureOutput" program that capture the output, write to stdout, and in my java code to launch "CaptureOutput" and read its stdput.

Ugly, but might work.

So answer in other languages is also okay with me.

Comment: @amicngh I'm running on Windows 7

Comment: do you have access to other process to trigger from any where like java

Comment: @amicngh Sorry, I didn't understand your meaning...

Answer (score 1):

First let me say that what you're asking breaks all the rules of process isolation.
If your process does not create the process whose output you want to capture, and you also don't have access to modify the calling process (command shell? service manager? you haven't said which). Then your only chance, and it is a slim one at best, is to inject a thread into the process and while all its other threads are suspended, alter the global stdout (and stderr?). This can only be done by a process with full access privileges to the target process. Performing such surgery on a running process is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Another extreme alternative would be to extract all the runtime information you can about the process, kill the original and start your own copy with the redirection you want.
That would probably be frowned upon though...

Comment: Further refs await the keen/desperate querant.

Comment: A combination of SetStdHandle and Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces on codeproject might get you there.

I must stress "might get you there".
Sorry but I have to say this is just a bad idea. Find a log file solution or talk to the developers of the program or the sysadmin or something.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is pretty dangerous. It would be very easy to accidentally corrupt the memory of process you're trying to get into. Test, test, test. Then test some more. And good luck - I know I wouldn't want to have to pull this off.

This article - [API Hooking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37228/API-Hooking-LoadLibrary) - explains how to get started with what you want (using C++). Once you have your code injected into a running process, there are other Windows API calls to replace STDOUT (e.g. [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over when the process starts?  If so, you could start the process and have it pipe its stdout to a file  which could be read or to another program you write that could log it in a database, event viewer, etc.

Comment: No, I don't have control. As I said: I didn't create the process.

Comment: Could you compile this other process?

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, check out the operating system's IPC mechanisms such as message queues, pipes, shared memory, and sockets.  These mechanisms allow for [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).  Although, if your particularly interested in a program's output, a work-around could just have the first process output the data out to disk onto a file, and read with a separate process.  In this way, you could use multiple languages for the task.  A simple example would be to have C++ write some data out to a file, and use JAVA read/use the data, given the same file.  Hope I came close to answering, if at all.